# Project with path ':realm' could not be found in project ':app'. realm

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I'm using realm in react-native. After 'rnpm link realm', I meet the problem "Project with path ':realm' could not be found in project ':app'. realm", when run 'react-native run-android'

Comment: Did you tried clearing rebuilding app from android studio after the change?

Comment: Please show your /android/settings.gradle and /android/app/build.gradle

Comment: thanks, I finally fix this problem by adding this in setting.gradle         
  
`include ':realm' project(':realm').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../node_modules/realm/android')`